# How to bend one side of a planar mesh fade the bending effect towards the other side

Tags: modeling

I couldn't figure out how to bend one side of a planar mesh like the edges on that side follow a circle. I also want this bending effect to fade smoothly towards the other edge. It is like square(projected) piece cut out from a sphere but I want to control the fading effect and I also want one side of the piece to be a line. I thought, this is a primitive thing, it cannot be considered as "do the modeling for me" request. I'm sorry, If I'm not in the right place to ask such a question. I tried different modifiers but I couldn't converge to what I was willing to see. What is the easiest way of doing this in blender?

Edit: I tried to sketch it:
In this sketch, side view shows that from B to C it is bended. This is the final thing that I want to model. Then, I will repeat this round a cylinder. That part is easy. But, initially, I have to figure out how to bend one side of the mesh from B to C like in the first figure. The edges connected to the corner A are just lines. And the shape is symmetrical.
[image]

Comment: If you could add a few pictures of the effect you're looking for that would help a lot. At the minute it's a little difficult to understand what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: is this what you're looking for? http://i.stack.imgur.com/CY2e8.png

Comment: You can have a look at the Warp tool which can be found by searching using the Spacebar menu. I can't really post an answer since I never use it.  All I really know is that the 3D cursor position affects how it turns out.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is how to do it. Doing it with modifiers isn't possible as far as I know. If you need more control, comment.

1. Start by adding a circle.
2. rotate the circle by 90 degrees on the X axis(<kbd>R</kbd><kbd>X</kbd><kbd>90</kbd>).
3. Delete the bottom half of it.
4. Take the bottom to vertices and duplicate the by 2 units on the y axis (<kbd>Shift-D</kbd><kbd>Y</kbd><kbd>2</kbd>). 
   [image]
5. fill the two vertices.
6. hit (<kbd>Ctrl-R</kbd>).
7. add 1 less loop cuts then half the number of vertices in your circle you can use the scroll wheel to do this.
8. Join up all the faces (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>E</kbd>>*Bridge Edgeloops*).
9. add some loop cuts until your faces are about square.
10. tweak the shape using proportional editing.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Here is another way to model the smooth shape you want.

1. Add a circle
2. In *edit mode* delete the bottom half of it.
3. Extrude it to make a half cylinder shape. [image: extrude]
4. Add loop cuts for a smother final shape. [image: loop cuts]
5. Select the end edge loop.
6. Turn [*Proportional Editing*](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.6/Manual/3D_interaction/Transform_Control/Proportional_Edit) on.
7. Scale the end edge loop to 0 on the Z axis, adjust the Proportional Editing Influence to include all but the other end of the shape. [image: scale]
8. Again with the same Proportional Editing settings, move the end edge loop down until the bottom is flat. [image: grab]